# Why Riemann hypothesis and not Riemann's conjecture

Tags: soft-question, terminology, definition, conjectures, riemann-hypothesis

I have a stupid question. We say Erdös's conjecture, Goldbach's conjecture, Beal's conjecture... and so on. But we don't say 'Riemann's conjecture.' Instead we use the word 'hypothesis'. Why?

Comment: It's not a clear distinction on how people use the two terms in mathematics; they are often used as synonyms. It is correct to say that Riemanns hypotesis is a conjecture.

Comment: Probably "Riemann's hypothesis" is just older terminology.

Comment: I think it's just lost in translation. In German, it's Riemann'sche Vermutung, which translates to Riemann Conjecture.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between "die Riemann-Vermutung" and "Riemanns Vermutung" in German. The former would be used to express an established state of affairs (THE one), while the latter could in principle be used for any conjecture stemming from Riemann (in proper context). It indeed seems that the "'s" was 'lost in translation' since this distinction on this semantic basis is not paralleled in English.

Comment: because it is more than a conjecture : several billions of zeros have been checked to be on $Re(s) = 1/2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an interchangeability, but one assumes hypothesis is more formal than a conjecture.

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128165210/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52249.html) for a better treatment of this question, by a mathematician.